# Problems setting up tomcat in intellij idea

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a simple test restful web service using intellij idea. I'm following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@jamsesso/starting-out-with-jersey-apache-tomcat-using-intellij-6338d93ffd40

But, i got some problems running it. Every time i go to `localhost:8080/` after running it, it shows me `error 404` and the message

```
The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

. And, in intellij, there is a extense list of errors. I'll put the first one here:

```
13-Jan-2019 15:34:28.861 GRAVE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
```

At the beggining, it shows this:

```
F:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\bin\catalina.bat run
[2019-01-13 03:34:27,290] Artifact RestTeste:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\vitor\.IntelliJIdea2018.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_9_0_13_RestTeste"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "F:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.13"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "F:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111"
Using CLASSPATH:       "F:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\bin\bootstrap.jar;F:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.13\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

I think tomcat is maybe not with the right configs, but i couldn't find the ones that are wrong. I looked for environment variables and java version between intellij and tomcat, but i could say precisely if one of this was the problem. `Java_home` and `catalina_home` was set up to jdk folder and tomcat folder, respectively, and from what i saw, the versions were correct. I'm completely lost regarding this problem, and couldn't find any solution in more than 4 hours.

What could be the problem?

Am i missing some configuration step in tomcat or in intellij? I was reading the running.txt file inside of tomcat folder and followed the steps to configure it but no success.

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**: I tried to do other stuff so it's worth pointing out here. I tried the install through the .exe downloaded in apache tomcat website. It worked fine, i started it and at localhost:8080 it shows me the default tomcat page. I then went to intellij and added this new version of tomcat to my application servers, located in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0. When i tried to run it, at first, it gave me the error that localhost was already in use, but i closed tomcat and tried again and it worked. At least, partially. It gives me the same errors than before and running only localhost:8080 gives me the message "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists." again. I tried changing my jre_home variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191, as the answer from yan suggested, but it continued to show Using JRE_HOME: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111". If i echo %JRE_HOME% in cmd it will print the jre path, not the jdk one. Can you guys help me?
To add the application server, i simply selected tomcat and the path to it.
The initial text, again:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\vitor\.IntelliJIdea2018.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_9_0_8_RestTest"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

An image of my envinroment variables:[image]

**Update 2**: here's a print of my running configurations, as requested:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you added your artifact(s) in the Deployment tab (see screenshot below)!

[image: Run/Debug Configurations]

After do this, you run your project and it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

- First some background on how Tomee works: [Getting started with tomee](https://www.tomitribe.com/blog/getting-started-with-tomee/).
- Make sure tomcat is running in port 8080 and not somthing else, look at the tomcat cofig file(s) to find out where it should be running.
- Make sure your firewall is not blocking it although if its port 8080 it shouldn't .
- I've noticed that in the output:
  Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111 - its the jdk not jre.
- Another thing worth mentioning is that your app could deploy to something like: "localhost:8080/app_name" so try changing your running configurations in Intellij. 
  The root URL of your app is determined in  following tags in web/WEB-INF/web.xml:

  "servlet-name" and "url-pattern"
- Make sure your Intellij build produces a **.war exploded** artifact - check your project setting under "artifacts".

Comment: I tried but no success. See my update for more information. I added JRE_HOME but in intellij it keeps showing me he is using jdk, even though if a echo jre_home on cmd it prints me the jre path.

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is that your app could deploy to something like: "localhost:8080/app_name" so try to changing your running configurations in Intellij, post your running configurations in Intellij, moreover I believe you can change your JRE path in the running configurations, or the project settings.

Comment: I changed the JRE path in the edit configurations and the text of Using: JRE_HOME changed to the jre path in my computer. But. same error. I will update again with a print of my run configs.

Comment: Is your artifact is of type war exploded?

Comment: Yes, it was war exploded. I changed it and "worked". This last step made the localhost:8080 work! But now, every url i try gives me the error " The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.". Do you know what is it? And, can you explain to me how to know the complete url? My project is called RestTest, my web.xml has "/*" as url-pattern, and my resource class has @Path("/hello")

Comment: I don't get it. If i set my artifact to Web Application: Exploded, it gives me that ton of errors. But if i select Web Application: Archive, it does give me only this error mentioned in the last answer here.