# Problems accessing restful web service

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, restful-url

To make some context, i asked this question last week with some problems configuring tomcat on my computer. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172059/problems-setting-up-tomcat-in-intellij-idea).
Well, now, i have it set up. I run it from intellij and the local page for tomcat at `localhost:8080/` shows up. But, in whatever other URL i try to navigate, it shows me the same message:

```
ERROR 404 - The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
```

I think i'm typing the URL wrong or something, but since i had so many problems setting it up (i still have some, because if i try to deploy a war exploded, not even the `localhost:8080/` shows up), it might be some other thing i'm not seeing.
Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>restTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And my web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>API</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>restTest</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>API</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My resource class:

```
package restTest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

My project structure:
[image]

And, i don't know if it's needed, but in the other question, it helped:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\vitor\.IntelliJIdea2018.2\system\tomcat\Tomcat_9_0_8_RestTest"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
```

I decided to ask another question because that one had a different intent, and i'm having different problems now (although some of the other one remains).

I tried this URLs:

```
localhost:8080/hello
localhost:8080/RestTest/hello
localhost:8080/restTest/hello
localhost:8080/restTest
```

But all of them gave me the same error. Am i ponting to the wrong URL, or is something wrong with my tomcat configuration? Like i said, when i try to deploy a war exploded, it shows a lot of errors mentioned in the last question.

Thanks!

Edit: the errors when i try to deploy a war exploded are:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
 javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method manageApp
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
```

Comment: *when i try to deploy a war exploded, it shows a lot of errors* - so maybe these errors need fixing, but unless you actually show us what they are, it is pretty hard to help you.

Comment: Since you are using Maven, move content of the `web` directory under the `webapp` directory in `src/main` directory according to Maven standard directory layout: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: @ScaryWombat i'll add the errors on the question.

Comment: @Andrey did that, but no change

Comment: *com/google/common/base/Function* - well as the JVM did not find this on your classpath, the webapp could not be loaded

Comment: You mean the env variable classpath? Tbh it was not there but it's still the same. Sorry for the delay